# How do I Call Post API in python?

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

Uploads a file using POST semantics.
URL Structure   https://apidocs.zoho.com/files/v1/upload?authtoken=AuthToken&scope=docsapi
Parameters

---

Parameter   Value   Description

---

filename    string  Mandatory. Name of the file to be uploaded

---

fid         string  Optional. id of the folder where files to be uploaded to a folder

---

content     string  Mandatory. Actual document content to be uploaded

```
import requests

AuthToken = "xyz"
fileName = "a.xsl"
FolderID = "xxxxxxxxx"
myfiles = {'file': ('report.xls', open('pathToFile', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
URL = "https://apidocs.zoho.com/files/v1/upload?authtoken=" + AuthToken + "&scope=docsapi"
mydata = {
    'filename': fileName,
    'fid': FolderID,
    'content': myfiles
}
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=mydata)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

However, I am getting error as "No File Specified or Empty File"
Though file contains data..